# Print range of memory addresses in qemu

Tags: c, linux, memory, qemu

I am new to qemu development. I wanted to print the corresponding addresses involved when a memory has been assigned to a virtual machine.

For example, when i invoke the following command

qemu-system-i386 ubuntu.img -m 1G

I need to be able to print the virtual addresses and physical addresses involved. Like above 1G memory involved:

Guest Virtual    Addr = 0x12345678..to 0x87654321..

Guest Physical Addr = 0x23456781..to 0x74536733..(This is the one that gets mapped to host virtual memory if my understanding is right).

Note:
Above numbers are just for explanation.

When I looked into the source code of qemu, I see that this size whatever we are mentioning in the command here is assigned as a part of |ram_addr_t| block. But I am not able to find as how to proceed to find the offset for this size.Kindly help me in this regard at the earliest.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how QEMU works. Every QEMU VM exists as a process on the host system, like any other process such as a shell or your desktop window manager. As such, its virtual address range is 0 to 2^N-1 (where N is 32 or 64). Mapping that to physical memory works the same as with any other process, and will not likely be static or contiguous. Also, this isn't a programming question...

Comment: I know that host treats qemu vm as a process. The question is not wrt to host system. I want to encrypt the contents of certain parts of memory that qemu assigns to the vm. This memory that qemu assigns is from a pool that it maintains (of course it gets mapped to virtual memory on the host) but has nothing to do with the host memory management system. I wanted to know this range of addresses that qemu assigns to the vm and is maintained by qemu, not the host. So, you need to modify qemu source code for it.Kindly let me know if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, I *think* what you want to do is not map guest virtual address to guest physical address (per the post), but guest physical address to host virtual address.

The mapping between guest physical and guest virtual is (mostly) controlled by the guest OS. If you are really are trying to look at guest physical to guest virtual, that will be target specific. Some qemu targets do not even have such a mapping (flat address space).

I would start by looking at the source for `memory.c` and `memory_mapping.c`.

Below is an excerpt from `exec.c` which converts a target a target (guest) virtual address into a target physical address, and manipulates memory there. Is that what you needed?

```
int cpu_memory_rw_debug(CPUState *cpu, target_ulong addr,
                        uint8_t *buf, int len, int is_write)
{
    int l;
    hwaddr phys_addr;
    target_ulong page;

    while (len > 0) {
        page = addr & TARGET_PAGE_MASK;
        phys_addr = cpu_get_phys_page_debug(cpu, page);
        /* if no physical page mapped, return an error */
        if (phys_addr == -1)
            return -1;
        l = (page + TARGET_PAGE_SIZE) - addr;
        if (l > len)
            l = len;
        phys_addr += (addr & ~TARGET_PAGE_MASK);
        if (is_write) {
            cpu_physical_memory_write_rom(cpu->as, phys_addr, buf, l);
        } else {
            address_space_rw(cpu->as, phys_addr, buf, l, 0);
        }
        len -= l;
        buf += l;
        addr += l;
    }
    return 0;
```

Finally, I think you might get more help on the qemu IRC channel than here.

Comment: Yes. I need to map from guest physical to host virtual. Whats the function I need to look into?That is I need to reserve certain pages of total pages that is assigned to target or guest image and then release them under certain conditions.Plz help.